# Redirect broken link to other page using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know there's already alot of question like this that has been asked and answered here but I can't find the right answer for my problem. I have a link like this `http://domain.com/announcements` and I want to redirect that to this page `http://domain.com/updates`.

How can I do that using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /announcements /updates
```

Or if you already have mod_rewrite rules, you should stick with just using mod_rewrite and add this above your other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^announcements/?$ /updates [L,R=301]
```